# Angular schema form destroyStrategy works only on siblings that are array of objects. It does not work on other siblings

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I have not been successful in getting the destroy strategy to work on any sibling properties or sibling objects. It only works on sibling array of objects. Please check this example:

```
$scope.schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "propertyOne": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["option1", "option2"],
            "title": "Property One Select"
        },
        "propertyTwo": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["option3", "option4"],
            "title": "Property Two Select"
        },
        "objectOne": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "objectOnePropertyThree": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["option5","option6"],
                    "title": "Property Three Select"
                }
            }
        },
        "arrayOfObjects": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
               "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "arrayObjectPropertyFour": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": ["option7","option8"],
                            "title": "Property Four Select"
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": ["propertyOne"]
};


$scope.form = [{
    "key": "propertyOne"
}, {
    "key": "propertyTwo",
    "condition": "model.propertyOne === \"option1\""

},{
    "key": "objectOne.objectOnePropertyThree",
    "condition": "model.propertyOne === \"option1\""
},{
    "key": "arrayOfObjects",
    "condition": "model.propertyOne === \"option1\""
},
{
    "type": "submit",
    "title": "Save"
}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mutharasus/dp18a70b/
In here if you select the first dropdown to "Option1" then select all the other dropdowns and save. Then go back and switch the first dropdown to "Option2" and save you can see that only the very last array of objects is removed with the destroy strategy.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in angular-schema-form? I looked under the issues that are currently open in the github project and I do not see an open issue about this.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct, it's not currently behaving the way that you expect when an individual field is removed from the view because of a condition.

Here's what's happening: under the "old" bundled decorators for ASF, each field-type decorator is rendered on the page within an outer  tag. The contents of the appropriate field template are then processed and rendered. Condition logic applies to everything within the  tag, but not to the  tag itself. Normally, this would be fine, but the destroyStrategy logic was assigned to the $destroy event of the  tag.  The end result is that the $destroy event will never fire unless the entire  tag would be removed from the DOM. This is why the model values in the array of objects are being cleaned up - the container is removed when the "model.propertyOne === 'option1'" condition fails, which cascades the $destroy event to each object in the array.

I think that this got overlooked with the creation and release of the new builder, because I raised the issue at the end of the PR for the feature (https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/pull/371).

On the bright side, the new builder approach (which you can use by adding the bootstrap-decorator file from https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form-bootstrap) doesn't have this issue. Instead, the destroyStrategy logic is applied via directive to the form fields because the  tag is no longer used. Unless you have a need to stay with the old decorators at this time, I suggest grabbing the new ones and giving them a try.

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks. I will check out the new builder and see if that solves my problem.